# How to find remaining date range in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursive-query, date-range

I have a sqlite database like

**ID      Fromdate         Todate**

**1 2023-04-02  2023-04-07**

**2 2023-04-05  2023-04-06**

**3 2023-04-09  2023-04-11**

**2 2023-04-09  2023-04-16**

from temptable.

Now i am getting stack to create a query in *sqlite*

when I search date From 2023-04-02 to To 2023-04-30 the remaining date range for each id should populate.

**Expected output**

**ID      Fromdate         Todate**

**1 2023-04-08  2023-04-30**

**2 2023-04-02  2023-04-04**

**2 2023-04-07  2023-04-08**

**2 2023-04-17  2023-04-30**

**3 2023-04-02  2023-04-08**

**3 2023-04-12  2023-04-30**

Please Help me

I tried many thing but failed

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. What's the input? What's the expected output? Show an example of what you tried and describe how it failed.

Comment: How do you get that result from that input?

Comment: What are thiose (duplicate) IDs?

Answer (score 1):

For every ID you want intervals of days not covered by the original set of intervals within the required period.

Provided your original intervals don't overlap within the same id. Find left, right intervals and union

```
with tbl(ID, Fromdate, Todate) as (
  -- sample data
  select 1, julianday('2023-04-02'), julianday('2023-04-07') union all
  select 2, julianday('2023-04-05'), julianday('2023-04-06') union all
  select 3, julianday('2023-04-09'), julianday('2023-04-11') union all
  select 2, julianday('2023-04-09'), julianday('2023-04-16') 
),
params (ds, de) as (
  -- period to search within
  select julianday('2023-04-02'), julianday('2023-04-30')
), 
leftintvls as (
  -- the closest end of intervals relative to current interval start
  select id,  
    (select max(t2.Todate)+1  
     from tbl t2 
     where t2.id = t.id and t2.Todate < t.Fromdate ) ms, Fromdate-1 me
  from tbl t
  -- only itervals overlapping with the requierd period
  join params p on t.Fromdate <= p.de and p.ds <= t.Todate 
    --  starting later than required period starts
    and t.Fromdate > p.ds
),
rightintvls as (
  -- the closest start of interval relative current interval end
  select id, Todate+1 ms,  
    (select min(t2.Fromdate) - 1  
     from tbl t2 
     where t2.id = t.id and t2.Fromdate > t.Todate ) me
  from tbl t
  -- only itervals overlapping with the requierd period
  join params p on t.Fromdate <= p.de and p.ds <= t.Todate 
     --  ending earlier than required period ends
     and t.Todate < p.de  
)
select id, date(ifnull(ms, p.ds)) fromd, date(me) tod
from leftintvls
cross join params p
where ifnull(ms, p.ds) <= me  
  
union 
  
select id, date(ms),  date(ifnull(me, p.de))
from rightintvls
cross join params p
where ms <= ifnull(me, p.de)
order by id, fromd
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UmKfW7ny)